# I'm getting: exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation

Tags: c#, iis, handler

I´m getting the exception when I try to open my page:

> *An unhandled exception occurred and the process was terminated.*
>
> Application ID: /LM/W3SVC/6/ROOT/ROXY/es
>
> Process ID: 2972
>
> Exception: System.InvalidOperationException
>
> Message: Handle is not initialized.
>
> StackTrace:
>   at System.WeakReference.set_Target(Object value)
>   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.CloseConnection(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
>   at System.Data.Odbc.OdbcConnection.Close()
>   at DsNet.CUIHandler.CloseConn()
>   at DsNet.CUIHandler.Finalize()

An in the page I get the error:

> *Message: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.*

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The bug in the page sounds unrelated, and should be investigated by catching and logging it. If you do end up catching a `TargetInvocationException`, then you can get the *actual* exception via the `.InnerException`.

Re the other issue: what is DsNet? Is that your code? or a library you are using? Either way, it sounds like it has a bug in the finalizer (touching managed objects is a *really* bad idea in a finalizer). I expect you may be able to make this less grumpy by using `using` around whetever is DsNet, so that it gets *disposed* in regular code, rather than *finalized* in the GC sweep. The only "hit" I'm getting in google for `DsNet.CUIHandler` is *this question* - so I'm *guessing* that is your code. If so: don't touch other managed objects in a finalizer.

Comment: That's the problem, DsNet is a library I am using and I have not access to modify it. Any way to identify the problem? The site was working fine for years

Comment: @ErnestoRodriguez the finalizer (as part of GC) will happen at unpredictable times, so that should ideally be addressed separately; like I say, the best thing I can advise is : make sure you're using `using`, or otherwise disposing the `IDisposable` objects after you're done with them. Other than that: you haven't given much to go on... all I can say is "some kind of coding, configuration or environment issue". That doesn't help much...